# On AddingItem event in Document Library distinguish is it a document or a folder

Tags: 2007, development, document-library

`enter code here`I have a small issue, I cannot seems to find a way to find out what time of item is being added, so i have a method AddingItem and here i need to know is this item a FOLDER or just some other type of item.

Is there a way to do that, i suppose there is, but can anyone provide me some useful info?

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            //find if it is Folder that is being created

            // do some stuff

            // exit            

        }
```

I tried: `properties.ListItem.File`
But it returns null, how can i then know if it is folder or is it something else.

Answer (score 2):

Non of above answers will work as you can't get `Properties.Item` in Item Adding event.

Since its Item Adding you can use `properties.AfterUrl`to get item's name

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                this.DisableEventFiring();

                string ItemName = properties.AfterUrl.ToString();
```

**Once you get item's name check if it has an extension if it does then its an Item otherwise a folder.**

You can use String.Split('.') to get extension of item, it might throw an exception though you be prepared to catch it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FileSystemObjectType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.filesystemobjecttype.aspx) property of the item to determine the type.

In order to access SPListItem object in the event receiver, use [properties.ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventproperties.listitem.aspx)

Comment: +1. Nice. Didn't know this. Does this work with list item's that are of a content type that has inherited 'Folder'?

Comment: is this for SharePoint 2010? in SharePoint 2007, there is nothing like that :(

Comment: According to MSDN, the property should be available in 2007 (WSS 3.0 to be more precise): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.filesystemobjecttype%28v=office.12%29.aspx